# how to install the latest version of tkinter on mac os

Tags: tkinter

i get an error like this: DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.

I am on mac os and writing code on vscode.
Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the `tkinter` code that Apple ships is hopelessly out of date - along with its versions of `bash`, `sed` and `find` - but that's another story.

IMHO, if you want an up-to-date `tkinter` you'd go to [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/) and install the latest/greatest Python from the Python Software Foundation.